# How to understand a result of TS code parse?

Tags: typescript

I got a enum type, as follow:

```
enum Days {Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat};
```

Actually, above is be parsed:

```
var Days;
(function (Days) {
    Days[Days["Sun"] = 0] = "Sun";
    Days[Days["Mon"] = 1] = "Mon";
    Days[Days["Tue"] = 2] = "Tue";
    Days[Days["Wed"] = 3] = "Wed";
    Days[Days["Thu"] = 4] = "Thu";
    Days[Days["Fri"] = 5] = "Fri";
    Days[Days["Sat"] = 6] = "Sat";
})(Days || (Days = {}));
```

I am curious about that whether `Days["Sun"] = 0` return 0 and `Days["Mon"] = 1` or not ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am curious about that whether Days["Sun"] = 0 return 0 and Days["Mon"] = 1 or not

Yes it does. This is [by design](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html) and standard way of coverting strings to enum members.

Comment: **Note that in JavaScript the assignment operator returns the assigned value** I understand from this in your gitbook. Thanks.